# Changing the category permalink structure

Tags: categories, permalinks, url-rewriting

Hopefully another simple one, I have some nested categories, like this:

```
- category-a
    - category-b
         -category-c
```

The permalink for category-c is as follows:

```
http://<domain>/category/category-a/category-b/category-c/
```

What I'd really like is for the permalink to not include any parent categories, instead it would become this:

```
http://<domain>/category/category-c/
```

Is there a way this can be achieved? I have some categories that do nothing but group sub-categories together, thus I don't really want them displaying to my users.

Many thanks!

Comment: We also have [a related question aboute removing the parents and the `/category/` prefix](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6106/remove-parent-category-from-permalink-basically-only-have-the-child-category). This is more complicated because it requires extra rewrite rules, and includes redirection for old-style links.

Comment: And we also have [a question about removing parent categories from *post* permalinks](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4095/filtering-categories-in-the-permalink-structure).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following code changes all links to category archives so they don't include the parent category:

```
add_filter( 'category_link', 'wpse7807_category_link', 10, 2 );
function wpse7807_category_link( $catlink, $category_id )
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $catlink = $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct();

    if ( empty( $catlink ) ) {
        $catlink = home_url('?cat=' . $category_id);
    } else {
        $category = &get_category( $category_id );
        $category_nicename = $category->slug;

        $catlink = str_replace( '%category%', $category_nicename, $catlink );
        $catlink = home_url( user_trailingslashit( $catlink, 'category' ) );
    }
    return $catlink;
}
```

Add the code to the `functions.php` of your theme.

Comment: That's exactly what I was after, does exactly what I need without editing any core files and without using a plugin (which is preferable for me). Many thanks @Jan Fabry

Comment: Will your code work for removing parent category page permalink as well?

Comment: @Mars: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you want to ask. If you have a subcategory at `/category/fruit/banana/` the links will be changed to `/category/banana/`. The `/category/fruit/` archive will stay at that location.