# Change permalinks with ACF values

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, advanced-custom-fields

I am running a site where I let users create a profile, which is a custom post type, which is submitted/edited through an ACF front-end form. Everything works as expected, except when users both use the same 'headline' (which is sanitized and used as permalink).

I want the permalink to have the following 'structure': /post-type/city/{post-title}-{post-id}. My thought was to add a post id, so each link would be unique, but I now found out this is not the case.

If I would have 2 profiles:
www.domain.com/profile/city/i-am-cool-123
www.domain.com/profile/city/i-am-cool-456

Then www.domain.com/profile/city/i-am-cool-456 redirects to www.domain.com/profile/city/i-am-cool-123.

I knew you can't have 2 the same permalinks, but I might have misunderstood how permalinks are 'registered'.

Below is my code.

First I've added the necessary query vars for the new vars and added custom rewrite tags.

```
function sd_custom_rewrite_tag() {
    add_rewrite_tag( '%city%', '([^&]+)', 'city=' );
    add_rewrite_tag( '%postname%', '([^&]+)', 'name=' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'sd_custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0 );

function sd_add_query_vars( $vars ) {
    $vars[] = "city";
    $vars[] = "postname";

    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'sd_add_query_vars' );
```

To get the permalink I want, I have the following code in place.

```
function sd_new_profile_permalink( $permalink, $post, $leavename = false ) {

    if ( strpos( $permalink, '%city%' ) === FALSE ) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    // Get post
    if ( ! $post ) {
        return $permalink;
    }

    // Get custom info
    $city_info  = get_field( 'sd_city_selector', $post->ID );
    $post_slug  = $post->post_name;
    if ( ! is_wp_error( $city_info ) && ! empty( $city_info ) ) {
        $city_replace  = str_replace( '\'', '', $city_info[ 'cityName' ] );
        $city_replace  = str_replace( ' ', '-', $city_replace );
        $city_slug     = strtolower( $city_replace );
        $new_permalink = str_replace( array( '%city%', '%postname%', '%post_id%' ), array( $city_slug, $post_slug, $post->ID ), $permalink );

        return $new_permalink;
    }
    return $permalink;
}
add_filter( 'post_link', 'sd_new_profile_permalink', 10, 3 );
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'sd_new_profile_permalink', 10, 3 );
```

So far nothing weird is happening, this is all doing what it's supposed to do, but now we get down to the issue (I think).

I update the slug through a WPDB action, after the post is submitted, as seen below.

```
function set_profile_title_from_headline( $post_id ) {

    if ( empty( $_POST[ 'acf' ] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST[ 'acf' ][ 'field_57e3ed6c92ea0' ] ) ) {
        $entered_title = $_POST[ 'acf' ][ 'field_57e3ed6c92ea0' ];
        $cleaned_title = preg_replace( '/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\s]/', '', $entered_title ); 
        $post_name     = sanitize_title( $cleaned_title );
        update_field( 'sd_ad_title', $cleaned_title, $post_id ); 

        global $wpdb;
        $wpdb->update(
            $wpdb->posts,
            array(
                'post_title'  => $cleaned_title,
                'post_name'   => $post_name
            ),
            array(
                'ID' => $post_id
            )
        );

        clean_post_cache( $post_id );

    }

}
add_action( 'acf/save_post', 'set_profile_title_from_headline', 20 );
```

And then finally I rewrite the url.

```
function sd_single_profile_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct( 'profile', 'profile/%city%/%postname%-%post_id%/', false );
    add_rewrite_rule( 'profile\/([a-z-]+)\/(.+)-[0-9]+\/?$', 'index.php?post_type=profile&p=$matches[2]&city=$matches[1]&name=$matches[2]', 'top' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'sd_single_profile_rewrite' );
```

Basically my question is: Is there a way to 'do' what I want to do ?
And if so, how :)

Comment: You should check if there is a redirect, and if there is which part of the core code is responsible for it. In addition did you save your permalinks? Did you actually verify that the rewrite rules are actually there?

Comment: If I am understanding his goal, he wants `/foo/this-is-a-slug/` and `/bar/this-is-a-slug/` to direct to different posts. And I don't think that is practically possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/changing-the-category-permalink-structure?rq=1

Comment: @MarkKaplun how to check for redirect ? Yes permalinks were saved. I checked with Monkeyman rewrite analyzer and it showed nothing unexpected.. Slam you are misunderstood. Has nothing to do with taxonomy.

Comment: you can just check the developer tools of the browser to see if the first response is a redirect (probably 302), or check the server log. If still not it, try to use the query monitor plugin to get a better idea which rewrite rule matches and with which parameters

Comment: .... maybe you should try to remove the post name from the rewrite rule... maybe it has a priority over the post id

Comment: I have found an acceptable solution. It's not 100% what I want, but it's close enough. I have removed the entire rewrite part and I made a small change to the wpdb query.
`'post_name'   => strtolower( get_field( 'sd_city_search_value', $post_id ) ) . '-' . $post_name . '-' . $post_id`. I changed the use of / to - and now I include everything in the new permalink.

Comment: It does need some further tweaking to sanitize it, but the concept is working, that is what is most important. A / instead of a - is nothing to be worried about right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was thinking too 'difficult'. Instead of rebuilding a new permalink structure I could have easily updated the new permalink the way I want to have it.

So I deleted the entire rewrite part and changed the query in acf/save_post to the following:

```
if ( ! empty( $_POST[ 'acf' ][ $ad_title ] ) ) {

    $entered_title = $_POST[ 'acf' ][ $ad_title ];
    $cleaned_title = preg_replace( '/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\s]/', '', 
    $entered_title ); // Removes special chars.
    $post_name     = sanitize_title( $cleaned_title );
    $city_name     = get_field( 'sd_city_search_value', $post_id );
    $new_slug      = strtolower( $city_name ) . '-' . $post_name . '-' . $post_id;

    // update acf field
    update_field( 'sd_ad_title', $cleaned_title, $post_id );

    // update post status + post title (if needed)
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->update(
        $wpdb->posts,
        array(
            'post_title'  => $cleaned_title,
            'post_name'   => strtolower( get_field( 'sd_city_search_value', $post_id ) ) . '-' . $post_name . '-' . $post_id
        ),
        array(
            'ID' => $post_id
        )
    );

    clean_post_cache( $post_id );

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Are `/i-am-cool-123` and `i-am-cool-456` actually two different posts?

If so then sure you want two different permalinks.

But your use case sounds like you have one post and you want to track visits from different pages on your site. In which case you might want to [add UTM codes to the ends of you URLs](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-track-links-in-wordpress-using-google-analytics/) to track them.

Edit: I think you mean you'd have two profiles... but in different cities? The `i-am-cool-123` part is the post name and they must be unique. There doesn't seem to be a point in creating an `i-am-cool-234` and redirecting it to `i-am-cool-123` because no-one would be able to visit the content at `i-am-cool-234` — clicking that link would take you to `i-am-cool-123`.

The part before the post_name, the rest of the URL... doesn't matter. `red/apples` and `yellow/apples` both would normally go to the post named `apples`. The path is generated by Wordpress and multiple paths can go to the same post (which is why for SEO purposes it's a good idea to define a canonical URL).

You might be able to make a custom permalink that parses the path. Maybe `yellow/apples` redirects to `yellow/apples-yellow` and `red/apples` redirects to `red/apples-red`, but your rewrite would need to grab something from the path to extract and put at the end of the post name. Sounds like a PITA.

But nothing stops you from having the same post titles. `/i-am-cool-123` and `i-am-cool-456` would both appear in the URL, but the title of both pages would still be I Am Cool.

Comment: This do not actually answer the question, it is more like a very long comment.

Comment: It was an answer and then I realized I didn't understand the question correctly. Then it became more of a comment. I'll delete it if I'm still not understanding the OP's goals.

Comment: basically the OP wants a URL structure like it is here, part name, part numerical ID. The reason is to automatically generate a unique slug without enforcing a unique title, but still have the title part of the URL for SEO

Comment: I think you have worded it correctly @MarkKaplun.
The slug is taken from a (sanitized) user inputted acf field, as is the city.

I added the post ID since I (incorrectly assumed) it would create a unique URL because I already expected some users to use the same headline.

I'm open to any solutions/suggestions, but ideally I want to create a unique URL so two profiles can have the same headline. *edit* it just hit me... since I already change the post_name. Can't I easily add the post id there ??

Comment: btw SEO is not involved here. I just like pretty links without the -2 addition ;)

Comment: yeh @Beee, it is just a more common reason for this kind of thing ;)

Comment: what about adding the post_id into the post_name when changing it in the db. do you think that would work ?