# Wordpress archive permalink with leaf category

Tags: permalinks

Wordpress Category Archive permalinks set up with %category% include the full category tree. I want to see only the leaf category in the URL, not the full tree.

Example:

```
Wordpress Category: recipes > baking > bread
current permalink for archive: domain.com/recipes/baking/bread
desired permalink: domain.com/bread
```

I've been searching the web without any idea how to hook or filter this change into my wordpress code, so any ideas and help is highly welcome. thanks Jan

Comment: Seems like you already found your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51457564/wordpress-archive-permalink-with-leaf-category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching I found the answer, in case someone else has a similar issue. The following code will leave only the deepest category in the archive permalink and will remove all parent categories.

```
add_filter( 'category_link', 'wpse7807_category_link', 10, 2 );
function wpse7807_category_link( $catlink, $category_id )
{
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $catlink = $wp_rewrite->get_category_permastruct();

    if ( empty( $catlink ) ) {
        $catlink = home_url('?cat=' . $category_id);
    } else {
        $category = &get_category( $category_id );
        $category_nicename = $category->slug;

        $catlink = str_replace( '%category%', $category_nicename, $catlink );
        $catlink = home_url( user_trailingslashit( $catlink, 'category' ) );
    }
    return $catlink;
}
```

kudos to [Changing the category permalink structure](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7807/changing-the-category-permalink-structure).

Answer (score 0):

You can filter [`term_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/term_link/) to modify any taxonomy URL generated by the API. In this case, we only need the filter, as the default rewrite rules will handle this modification for the incoming requests. If you're doing any sort of change that introduces a new URL pattern, you will also need to add new rules or change the existing ones so these new URLs can successfully parse into the correct queries and not just 404.

If you look at the [`get_term_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_link/) API function source, you will see the branch where it checks if it's a hierarchical taxonomy. I just copy/pasted some bits from the non-hierarchical case so the output is the same as a non-hierarchical term.

```
add_filter( 'term_link', 'wpd_term_link_filter', 10, 3 );
function wpd_term_link_filter( $url, $term, $taxonomy ) {
    if( 'category' == $taxonomy ){
        global $wp_rewrite;
        $termlink = $wp_rewrite->get_extra_permastruct( $taxonomy );
        $termlink = str_replace( "%$taxonomy%", $term->slug, $termlink );
        $url = home_url( user_trailingslashit($termlink, 'category') );
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Milo, I found a similar solution (see my answer below) thanks to your explanation. Works now like a charm!